How to show top 5 measurements sorted in descending order according to their highest value in influxdb
image of measurements
Hey does anyone know how to How to show top 5 measurements sorted in descending order according to their highest value in influxdb.
So I have measurements of multiple URLS with value field (for eg - /hi, /test.php etc along with their counts) I want to display top 5 most frequently visited URLS in grafana. how do I do that?
I currently could only come up with -  select max("value") from /^/.*$/; but that shows highest value per measurement of all measurements. I want to show only top 5 measurements by sorting them in descending order based on their highest value. if there is not a query available, let me know if I can use any transformation in grafana to achieve this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
